# How do I compare iterators?

Tags: testing, rust, iterator

I want to compare to iterators in a test case. Unfortunately, `assert_eq!` does not like to be passed iterators.
One workaround looks like this:

```
let mut a = 0..5;
let mut b = 0..6;

assert!(a.by_ref().zip(b.by_ref()).all(|(a, b)| a == b));
assert_eq!(a.next(), None);
assert_eq!(b.next(), None);
```

But it requires 3 (or at least) 2 lines for the test and the iterator needs to be made mutable. Is there anything better?

Comment: Why my search didn't turn up this duplicate is a mystery to me.

Comment: What kind of searching did you do? `site:stackoverflow.com rust compare iterator` found the duplicate as my top Google result. Also, remember that votes are a reflection on the *post*, not the user. The downvote button states: *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*; I assume the downvoter thought that this question was not useful in light of the duplicate.

Comment: @Shepmaster Unfortunately, if you type `how do i compare iterators [rust]` into the search bar your question doesn't even show up on the first page. So at least this question adds value because now it can be found.

Comment: The Stack Overflow search engine is not great, but searching is a skill that can be improved as well. [`compare iterators [rust]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=compare+iterators+%5Brust%5D) finds it quickly. It's useful to remove fluff words when dealing with any search engine that isn't as smart as Google.

Comment: *because now it can be found* — perhaps. [`how do you compare iterators  [rust]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+do+you+compare+iterators++%5Brust%5D) doesn't find either post on the first page. However, you are right about the value of duplicates — they serve as signposts to existing answers, and that's a reason we wouldn't just vote to delete such a question.

Comment: @shepmaster For the same reason they should not be downvoted. I am currently incentivized by the stackoverflow karma system to delete this question myself.

Comment: That's always an option, certainly. You've still got a few thousand points, so ideally a few negative ones won't hurt in the long run. Incentives are a tricky business; I would hope you'd be encouraged to search more deeply next time, but that's my opinion (and I'm a believer in [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/155423)).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204429/discussion-between-sarien-and-shepmaster).

Answer (score 3):

There is [`Iterator::eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.eq). I think this should be the winner:

```
assert!(a.eq(b));
```

And it turns out there is [`itertools::assert_equal`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.1/itertools/fn.assert_equal.html):

```
let a = 0..6;
let b = 0..6;
    
itertools::assert_equal(a, b);
```

And it's not exactly pretty but here is a solution using [`zip_longest`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.2/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.zip_longest):

```
assert!(a.zip_longest(b).all(|thingy| thingy.as_ref().left() == thingy.as_ref().right()));
```

Comment: `assert!(a.eq(b));` is enough

Comment: @Boiethios simple `assert!` works but does have the drawback that the failure message doesn't tell you much